# Ordinal numbers as adverbs

Tags: adverbs, numbers

I was once told not to end "firstly [point 1], secondly [point2], thirdly [point 3]" in -ly and to leave them as first, second, third etc. Is this always true or only in certain situations? Is it ever correct to use the word "firstly"?

I came accross [this article](http://bretpimentel.com/why-tune-to-the-oboe/) where the author writes

> Firstly: hogwash. (True, the oboe doesn’t have a built-in tuning
>   slide. But an oboist can “tune” by switching reeds, and can humor
>   individual notes sharper or flatter on the fly, just like any wind
>   player.) Secondly: if we tune to the principal oboe because it can’t
>   be tuned, then what is the second oboist expected to do?

Is it correct to separate the ordinal numbers into different sentences like this? Is there a specific name for the speech pattern where people are making multiple arguments to prove a point?

Comment: Words aren't banned from the language just because someone doesn't like their use in applications. Use the -ly ones, or don't as you prefer.

Comment: "First," may be considered as a shortened form of "My first point is:" (or "Let us first consider that"). "Firstly," may be considered as a shortened form of "Let us firstly consider that". Sometimes, (1). etc are used.